# Different site different div content - Multisite

Tags: multisite, content

I have created numbers of websites. They are www.example.com, subsite1.example.com, subsite2.example.com and subsite3.example.com. I want to make a div that show different content. The example below is what i wanted.

Example: (this may not a correct code. But was trying to tell what i'm asking in this question).

```
    <?php if (is_site1()) { ?>
    <div class="div">
    Content for main site
    </div>
    <?php } ?>

    <?php if (is_site2()) { ?>
    <div class="div">
    content for sub site 1
    </div>
    <?php } ?>

    <?php if (is_site3()) { ?>
    <div class="div">
    content for sub site 2
    </div>
    <?php } ?>

    <?php if (is_site4()) { ?>
    <div class="div">
    content for sub site 3
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

This function is similar to code below:

```
<?php if (is_single() || is_achive()) { ?>
Show content
<? php } >
```

I want to place this function in my homepage. So that, the div takes effect everytime i switching the sites.

Please do let me know if you unsure of this question.
I'm wondering if this could be done? Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the sites have different wordpress installs? If so, they probably have different names and you could use

```
<div class="different-content">
if (get_bloginfo('name') == "site-1") {
    // show stuff for blog named "site-1"
} elseif (get_bloginfo('name') == "site-2") {
    // show stuff for blog named "site-2"
} else {
    //if it's not any of the sites above, show this
}
</div>
```

If they don't have different names you could do the same with

```
$host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$subdomain = array_shift((explode(".", $host)));
```

and checking for the subdomain instead of blog name.

---

New try.

In your functions.php add a function like this

```
function check_site($name) {
    if (get_bloginfo('name') == $name) { return true; }
    else { return false; }
}
```

now in your template (header.php/single.php etc..) you can use it like

```
<?php if (check_site('site_1')) { ?>
    <div class="div">
    Content for main site
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by different wordpress installs? I install my wordpress in my cpanel and enabled the multisite during the wordpress installation. By then, i added sub sites in the wordpress admin area. Are you trying to ask this?

Comment: Well yeah if you are using multisite all of the blogs should have their own settings and thus you should be able to check the site by name.

edit: I have to say I haven't really worked with multi site installations so I don't know the exact "if" sentence.

Check http://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/get_blog_details

Comment: I know the name of the site. But, i would like to ask, would you please show me a clearer instruction how to make it? I'm newbie in coding. And, i would like to make the code format as displayed in the question i asked. Just like if is_single() then the div shows A content , and if is_achive() then the div shows B content. Would be easier. Thanks! Jimihenrik.

Comment: The problem with "is_site1()" is that you have to define that function. So you would have to define a function for every different blog name then. Do you have one theme that covers all the sites? So are you just editing one set of files?

Comment: Yes! I have one theme covers all sites.

Comment: Ok, check the edit.

Comment: Hi Jimihenrik, awesome! The code works well and this is what i desired to get. Thanks so much! Appreciate your help! :)

Comment: Glad to help! :)